# javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Expected "/", got files

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am getting an error while trying to send an email with file attachment :

```
javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Expected '/', got files
    at javax.mail.internet.ContentType.<init>(ContentType.java:102)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1331)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1021)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:419)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1354)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2107)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2075)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:123)
```

The code below :

```
@Override
    public void execute(String filePath) {
        try {            
            Properties props = new Properties();                       
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");                                 

            Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {                    
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(GMAIL_ACCOUNT, GMAIL_PASSWORD);
                }
            });                    
            //We create a new mail message
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("esombugma@gmail.com"));
            //We constitute the list of recipients
            List<InternetAddress> recipList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(String address : this.getRecipients()) {
                recipList.add(new InternetAddress(address));
            }            
            InternetAddress[] iaTab = new InternetAddress[recipList.size()];
            iaTab = recipList.toArray(iaTab);
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, iaTab);
            msg.setSubject(this.getSubject());
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            //Create multi-part
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();            
            //Create a message part
            MimeBodyPart msgBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            msgBodyPart.setContent(this.getMessage(), this.getSubject());
            multipart.addBodyPart(msgBodyPart);
            //Adds attachment
            if((new File(filePath)).exists()) {
                MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
                try {
                    attachment.attachFile(new File(filePath));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(EmailSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }                
                attachment.setFileName((new File(filePath)).getName());
                multipart.addBodyPart(attachment);
            }            
            msg.setContent(multipart);            
            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(EmailSender.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }        
    }
```

And the code that generate the file is here :

```
public String getMissingReportName() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhh");
        return "C://Report//Report_" + sdf.format(new Date()) + ".xls";
}
```

Then a sample report file should be : `Report_20130512` for example.

Can someone explain to me what could be the orrigine of this error.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, the error. It come from my own code, exactly from this line `msgBodyPart.setContent(this.getMessage(), this.getSubject());`.
The paramater `this.getSubject()` witch is supposed to be the subject of my email, was autocompleted by my NetBeans IDE and I didn't saw it (since a week... OMG).
I have finally called `msgBodyPart.setText(this.getMessage())` and it works fine.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Something has messed up the Content-Type header, probably your application.  How are you setting the Content-Type?  There's lots of sample code on the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) and available for download form the [JavaMail project page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) in case you need help figuring out how to add an attachment.

Comment: Thank you. I still have the same error. I have added some code in my previous message.